# Android Multipart/form-data encoding for Facebook photo

Tags: android, facebook

The new Facebook Android SDK for uploading a photo to a Facebook album works like this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#publish) :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("source", "{image-data}");
/* make the API call */
new Request(
session,
"/me/photos",
params,
HttpMethod.POST,
new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
 }
).executeAsync();
```

What makes me confused is `{image-data}`, it said that the photo should be encoded as `multipart/form-data`, but from `params.putString("source", "{image-data}")` we can see that the second parameter of `putString()` should be a `String`, how can I encode an image file `multipart/form-data` and get the return value in`String` format?
Like this:

```
public String getImageFormData(File image){
   String imageValue;
    ...

    return imageValue;
}
```

Or do I understand it wrong, my question now is that I have the image file, how can I use the code above to successfully upload the image to Facebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sample code in the documentation seems to be mistaken. It seems like all you need is a (multipart) parameter named 'source' with the image data encoded.

Below is the code from the Facebook Android SDK used to convert the Bundle values into request parameters:

```
public void writeObject(String key, Object value) throws IOException {
    if (isSupportedParameterType(value)) {
        writeString(key, parameterToString(value));
    } else if (value instanceof Bitmap) {
        writeBitmap(key, (Bitmap) value);
    } else if (value instanceof byte[]) {
        writeBytes(key, (byte[]) value);
    } else if (value instanceof ParcelFileDescriptor) {
        writeFile(key, (ParcelFileDescriptor) value, null);
    } else if (value instanceof ParcelFileDescriptorWithMimeType) {
        writeFile(key, (ParcelFileDescriptorWithMimeType) value);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("value is not a supported type: String, Bitmap, byte[]");
    }
}

public void writeBitmap(String key, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    writeContentDisposition(key, key, "image/png");
    // Note: quality parameter is ignored for PNG
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    writeLine("");
    writeRecordBoundary();
    logger.appendKeyValue("    " + key, "<Image>");
}
```

In particular, for any Bitmaps in the Bundle, they serialize and create the appropriate multipart header for it. You can try to add your image to the Bundle as a Bitmap. Your `getImageFormData` method could then be something like:

```
public Bitmap getImageFormData(File image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath());
}
```

You can also try supplying a `ParcelFileDescriptor`, which gets serialized in a similar fashion:

```
public ParcelFileDescriptor getImageFormData(File image) {
    try {
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(image, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method may also be of interest (allows you to use url parameter instead of source):

```
/**
 * Creates a new Request configured to upload an image to create a staging resource. Staging resources
 * allow you to post binary data such as images, in preparation for a post of an Open Graph object or action
 * which references the image. The URI returned when uploading a staging resource may be passed as the image
 * property for an Open Graph object or action.
 *
 * @param session
 *            the Session to use, or null; if non-null, the session must be in an opened state
 * @param image
 *            the image to upload
 * @param callback
 *            a callback that will be called when the request is completed to handle success or error conditions
 * @return a Request that is ready to execute
 */
public static Request newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest(Session session,
        Bitmap image, Callback callback) {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle(1);
    parameters.putParcelable(STAGING_PARAM, image);

    return new Request(session, MY_STAGING_RESOURCES, parameters, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got one question, the code for convert bundle values into request parameters returns nothing, then what should I upload to Facebook. And you said the code in the documentation seems wrong, could you please also add the code for posting the photo to Facebook?

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao That code is from the Facebook SDK - it is just to understand how they handle parameters in the Bundle. Instead of 'params.putString("source", "{image-data}");', use 'params.putParcelable("source", bitmap);', where 'bitmap' is the image you want to upload (and an instance of the Bitmap class).

Answer (score 0):

change the method from **putString** to **putByteArray**